# Can't import .xlsx into R using readxl

Tags: r, excel, import, xlsx, readxl

Here's my code:

```
library(readxl)
datasets <- system.file("C:/Users/tyeg/Documents/Gamma Counter Processing/Inflammation/Study Compilation Sheet2.xlsx", package = "readxl")
read_excel(datasets)
```

Here's the error I get:

```
'' does not exist in current working directory
```

Comment: I think you're confused about what `system.file` does. Try just handing `read_excel` the full path that you're currently giving to `system.file`.

Comment: Sure. I'll try that. I was just following the format used in the documentation here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/readxl/readxl.pdf

Comment: It worked! Thanks. Any idea why the documentation had different syntax?

Comment: Yeah, like I said, `system.file` is being used there to retrieve the file path for files that are contained in the package **readxl** to be used as examples. Since everyone's computers are different, `system.file` is a way to reliably return a useable file path on different computers. The documentation for `read_excel` clearly says that `path` should simply be the file path to your document.